# Sudden Error: File does not exist

Tags: arduino-ide, attiny

I am suddenly getting an error every time I try to compile code in the IDE, even though every one of the sketches previously compiled just fine:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 7), Board: "MH-ET LIVE Tiny88(16.0MHz)"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\lrhorer\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=mhetlive:avr:MHETtiny88 -ide-version=10813 -build-path C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_609285 -warnings=all -build-cache C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_521731 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.micronucleus.path=C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\mhetlive\tools\micronucleus\2.0a4 -prefs=runtime.tools.micronucleus-2.0a4.path=C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\mhetlive\tools\micronucleus\2.0a4 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\4.8.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-4.8.1-arduino5.path=C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\4.8.1-arduino5 -verbose C:\Users\lrhorer\Documents\Arduino\sketch_feb27a\sketch_feb27a.ino

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\lrhorer\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=mhetlive:avr:MHETtiny88 -ide-version=10813 -build-path C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_609285 -warnings=all -build-cache C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_521731 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.micronucleus.path=C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\mhetlive\tools\micronucleus\2.0a4 -prefs=runtime.tools.micronucleus-2.0a4.path=C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\mhetlive\tools\micronucleus\2.0a4 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\4.8.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-4.8.1-arduino5.path=C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\4.8.1-arduino5 -verbose C:\Users\lrhorer\Documents\Arduino\sketch_feb27a\sketch_feb27a.ino

Using board 'MHETtiny88' from platform in folder: C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\mhetlive\hardware\avr\1.0.0

Using core 'tiny88' from platform in folder: C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\mhetlive\hardware\avr\1.0.0

Detecting libraries used...

"C:\\Users\\lrhorer\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=attiny88 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10813 -DARDUINO_AVR_DIGISPARKPRO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\lrhorer\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\mhetlive\\hardware\\avr\\1.0.0\\cores\\tiny88" "-IC:\\Users\\lrhorer\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\mhetlive\\hardware\\avr\\1.0.0\\variants\\tiny88" "C:\\Users\\lrhorer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_609285\\sketch\\sketch_feb27a.ino.cpp" -o nul -DARDUINO_LIB_DISCOVERY_PHASE

exec: "C:\\Users\\lrhorer\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++": file does not exist

Error compiling for board MH-ET LIVE Tiny88(16.0MHz).
```

The file indeed does not exist in that location.  What now?

Update:
Under the ATTinyCore compiler the missing file name is the same, but the directory is different:

```
exec: "C:\\Users\\lrhorer\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++": file does not exist
```

The latest version of the DigiStump compiler does not even have the MH-ET Live Tiny88 board compiler included.

I can get the code to compile under Linux, but I am having trouble uploading the binary to the board.  How can I take the binary code and upload it to the ATTiny88 board under either Linux or Windows 7?

Update:
I found three files quarantined by my anti-virus.  I restored the files, and now avr-g++.exe seems to be back where it belongs, and the compiler no longer claims the file is missing.  Now, however, it s complaining about not finding the stdlib.h library called from the Arduino.h library.

Update:
After I removed three files apparently related to the IDE from quarantine by my virus scanner, I deleted everything, and re-installed the IDE.  Now it compiles without error, but I cannot upload to the board in either Windows or Linux.  Of course I tried more than once to reinstall the Windows USB drivers, and they install without error, but the virtual device does not show up like it is supposed to, and the upload processor times out.

Comment: "This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences." Please post the detailed error messages.

Comment: install/reinstall the Arduino AVR core in Boards Manager

Comment: I added verbose output during compilation and edited the query to include the output..  I tried to re-install the AVR code.  There is nothing identified as the  "core".  I tried installing Arduino 1.8.5 and then reinstalling 1.8.6, and I tried removing and reinstalling the  MH-ET Live boards.  Neither worked.  There is a file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avr-g++.exe and a file C:\Users\lrhorer\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7\bin\avr-g++.exe.  Should I try re-installing the Digistump drivers from the command line?

Comment: the MH-ET boards package depends on Arduino AVR boards package. so again, reinstall the Arduino AVR boards package in Boards Manager. reinstalling the IDE doesn't reinstall Boards Packages

Comment: Didn't help.  See the update in the main text.

Comment: didn't help? you solved your original problem

Comment: Not by re-loading the Arduino AVR board.  That had no effect.  Now it compiles, but will no longer upload, which it also did just fine before this problem occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting / uninstalling the entire IDE and completely reinstalling allowed the code to compile, so I am closing this question.  It will not upload, so I will open another question.